# Как повесить двойной клик в react?

Tags: reactjs

Есть такой код. И при клике на элементе обычно срабатывает как двойной так и одиночный клик. А нужно чтобы если сработал двойной клик то одиночный бы не выполнялся.

```
onDoubleClick={e => {
          console.log("onDoubleClick");
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          setActiveFolder(id);
        }}
onClick={e => {
          console.log("onClick");
          setActiveFile(id);
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея взята отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element

```
onClick={e => {
    clearTimeout(this.timer); // Очищается ранее установленный таймер
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => { 
          // Если было одиночное нажатие, то действие выполнится через 250мс
          console.log("onClick");
    }, 250);
}}

onDoubleClick={e => {
    clearTimeout(this.timer); // Очистка таймера (если вдруг был одиночный клик)
    console.log("onDoubleClick");
}}
```